# cdkDragEntered not working on entering a cdkDrag item

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

can anybody tell me why `cdkDragEntered` is not firing the event?

Html:

```
html 

<div
  class="dragarea"
  [ngClass]="{ 'bg-blue': isDragging }"
  (cdkDragEntered)="onDragEnter($event)"
>
  drag area
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items" cdkDrag>{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drag',
  templateUrl: './drag.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drag.component.css'],
})
export class DragComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  isDragging!: boolean;
  onDragEnter(event: any): void {
    this.isDragging = true;
    console.log('hello');
  }
  items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'shray' },
    { id: 2, name: 'rocket' },
    { id: 3, name: 'cod' },
    { id: 4, name: 'halo' },
  ];
}
```

Css:

```css
.dragarea {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[stackblitz link](https://jake.stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-crud-example-bclpjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdrag%2Fdrag.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdrag%2Fdrag.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fdrag%2Fdrag.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I want to fire an event when a `cdkDrag` item is entered in a non-droppable, non-draggable container.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `cdkDropList` and `cdkDropListGroup` directive.

https://jake.stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-crud-example-blsuvt?file=src/app/drag/drag.component.html

Link to docs: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples